# Memory Error in Visual Studio 2022 don't know why

Tags: vb.net, out-of-memory, vsto

I work for a Tourism Agency and I made an Excel VSTO Workbook for the administration team. We've been using this workbook for around 3 months now and never had any problems until a couple of days ago when this memory error appeared.

The error message is the following:

System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Not enough memory resources are available to complete this operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000E (E_OUTOFMEMORY))'

What throws me off is the fact that I made 4 Modules that are an exact copy of each other, the only difference between them being that each one of them is made to administer a different service provider, and yet two of them work and the other two don't.

At first I thought it was because of the amount of data that was being analyzed but I don't think that's the case anymore because one of the modules that work is loading around 250 rows of data and one of the modules that doesn't has to load around 230 rows of data.

I'll leave the entire module at the end of this question.
The line that throws this error is the very last line of the Sub Procedure where it says:

```
Globals.shGuia.Range("b2", "t" & listaExcResumen.Count + 1).Value = arrGuia
```

Here are the things I've done to try to solve this issue.

- I added a variable to store listaExcResumen.Count + 1 instead of calculating it in the line of the code above.
- I run sfc /scannow in the cmd but there were no integrity violations.
- I run Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth to restor Windows Image.
- I increased IRPStackSize value up to 50 Hexadecimal.

None of this fixed my issue.

I am running Windows 11 and my pc specs are CPU: Ryzen 5600x/ RAM: 16gb/ GPU: RX 6700 XT/ PSU: Cooler Master MWE BRONZE 750W

```
Module TraerGuias
Sub CargarDatosGuia()

    'Resumen Reservation Structure
    Dim resExcResumen As New ReservaExcursion

    'Resumen List of Reservations
    Dim listaExcResumen As New List(Of ReservaExcursion)

    'DataBodyRange of the first column in the Resumen table
    Dim rgRango As Range = Globals.shResumen.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange

    'Headers of the Resumen table
    Dim rgRangoHeader As Range = Globals.shResumen.ListObjects(1).HeaderRowRange

    'Every column index that we need from the Resumen table 
    Dim iCliente, iGuia, iGuia2, iFechaExc, iPax,
        iCant, iExc, iExcEsp, iExtras, iObsProv As Integer
    iCliente = rgRangoHeader.Find("CLIENTE", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iFechaExc = rgRangoHeader.Find("FECHA", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iPax = rgRangoHeader.Find("PAX", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iCant = rgRangoHeader.Find("CANT", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iExc = rgRangoHeader.Find("EXCURSION", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iExcEsp = rgRangoHeader.Find("EXCURSION ESPECIAL", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iExtras = rgRangoHeader.Find("EXTRAS", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iGuia = rgRangoHeader.Find("Guia 1", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iGuia2 = rgRangoHeader.Find("Guia 2", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iObsProv = rgRangoHeader.Find("OBSERVACIONES PROVEEDORES", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2

    'Iterate through every cell in the first column of the Resumen table
    For Each cell As Range In rgRango
        'If the current row in the table has a guide asigned to it, then...
        If cell.Offset(0, iGuia).Value <> Nothing Or cell.Offset(0, iGuia2).Value <> Nothing Then
            'Create a Resumen Reservation
            With resExcResumen
                .observaciones = cell.Value
                .cliente = cell.Offset(0, iCliente).Value
                Try
                    .dtFechaExc = cell.Offset(0, iFechaExc).Value
                    .strFechaExc = Nothing
                Catch ex As Exception
                    .strFechaExc = cell.Offset(0, iFechaExc).Value
                    .dtFechaExc = Nothing
                End Try
                .pax = cell.Offset(0, iPax).Value
                .cant = cell.Offset(0, iCant).Value
                .excursion = cell.Offset(0, iExc).Value
                .excursionEspecial = cell.Offset(0, iExcEsp).Value
                .extras = cell.Offset(0, iExtras).Value
                .observacionesProveedores = cell.Offset(0, iObsProv).Value
            End With

            'If there's a guide assigned in the "GUIA 1" column
            If cell.Offset(0, iGuia).Value <> Nothing Then
                'Add the guide to the Resumen Reservation
                resExcResumen.guia = cell.Offset(0, iGuia).Value
                'Add the created Reservation to the Resumen List of Reservations
                listaExcResumen.Add(resExcResumen)
            End If

            'If there's a guide assigned in the "GUIA 2" column
            If cell.Offset(0, iGuia2).Value <> Nothing Then
                'Add the guide to the Reservation
                resExcResumen.guia = cell.Offset(0, iGuia2).Value
                'Add the created Reservation to the Resumen List of Reservations
                listaExcResumen.Add(resExcResumen)
            End If
        End If
    Next



    'Guide Reservation Structure
    Dim resExcGuia As New ReservaExcursion

    'Guide List of Reservations
    Dim listaExcGuia As New List(Of ReservaExcursion)

    'DataBodyRange of the first column in the Guide table
    rgRango = Globals.shGuia.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange

    'Headers of the Guide table
    rgRangoHeader = Globals.shGuia.ListObjects(1).HeaderRowRange

    'Every column index that we need from the Guide table
    Dim iObs, iDebe, iHaber, iFactura, iFechaFactura, iFechaPago, iEstadoPago, iObsPato, iTarSin, iTarCon As Integer
    iObs = rgRangoHeader.Find("OBSERVACIONES", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iCliente = rgRangoHeader.Find("CLIENTE", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iFechaExc = rgRangoHeader.Find("FECHA", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iPax = rgRangoHeader.Find("PAX", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iCant = rgRangoHeader.Find("CANT", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iExc = rgRangoHeader.Find("EXCURSION", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iExcEsp = rgRangoHeader.Find("EXCURSION ESPECIAL", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iExtras = rgRangoHeader.Find("EXTRAS", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iGuia = rgRangoHeader.Find("GUIA", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iObsProv = rgRangoHeader.Find("OBSERVACIONES PROVEEDORES", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iTarSin = rgRangoHeader.Find("TARIFA SIN IVA", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iTarCon = rgRangoHeader.Find("TARIFA SIN IVA", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iDebe = rgRangoHeader.Find("DEBE", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iHaber = rgRangoHeader.Find("HABER", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iFactura = rgRangoHeader.Find("FACTURA", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iFechaFactura = rgRangoHeader.Find("FECHA FACTURA", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iFechaPago = rgRangoHeader.Find("FECHA PAGO", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iEstadoPago = rgRangoHeader.Find("ESTADO DE PAGOS", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2
    iObsPato = rgRangoHeader.Find("OBSERVACIONES PATO", LookAt:=XlLookAt.xlWhole).Column - 2

    'If the Guide table is holding data
    If Not IsNothing(rgRango) Then
        'For each cell in the first column of the Guide table
        For Each cell As Range In rgRango
            'Add a Guide Reservation
            With resExcGuia
                .observaciones = cell.Value
                .guia = cell.Offset(0, iGuia).Value
                Try
                    .dtFechaExc = cell.Offset(0, iFechaExc).Value
                    .strFechaExc = Nothing
                Catch ex As Exception
                    .strFechaExc = cell.Offset(0, iFechaExc).Value
                    .dtFechaExc = Nothing
                End Try
                .cliente = cell.Offset(0, iCliente).Value
                .pax = cell.Offset(0, iPax).Value
                .cant = cell.Offset(0, iCant).Value
                .excursion = cell.Offset(0, iExc).Value
                .excursionEspecial = cell.Offset(0, iExcEsp).Value
                .extras = cell.Offset(0, 7).Value
                .observacionesProveedores = cell.Offset(0, iObsProv).Value
                .tarSinIva = cell.Offset(0, iTarSin).Value
                .tarConIva = cell.Offset(0, iTarCon).Value
                .debe = cell.Offset(0, iDebe).Value
                .haber = cell.Offset(0, iHaber).Value
                .factura = cell.Offset(0, iFactura).Value
                .fechaFactura = cell.Offset(0, iFechaFactura).Value
                .fechaPago = cell.Offset(0, iFechaPago).Value
                .estadoPago = cell.Offset(0, iEstadoPago).Value
                .observacionesPato = cell.Offset(0, iObsPato).Value
            End With
            'Add the Guide Reservation to the Guide List of Reservations
            listaExcGuia.Add(resExcGuia)
        Next
    End If

    'Stores the amount of Reservations in the Resumen List of Reservations
    Dim iTamañoListaResumen As Integer = listaExcResumen.Count - 1

    Dim i, j As Integer

sigExcursion:
    'If Guide List of Reservations has more than 0 Reservations
    If listaExcGuia.Count > 0 Then
        'Initialize j
        j = 0
        'For each Guide Reservation (excursionG) in Guide List of Reservations
        For Each excursionG As ReservaExcursion In listaExcGuia
            'If the value of estadoPago differs from "SIN IMPORTE", then...
            If excursionG.estadoPago <> "SIN IMPORTE" Then
                'LOOK FOR THAT SAME RESERVATION IN THE RESUMEN LIST OF RESERVATIONS
                For i = 0 To iTamañoListaResumen
                    'If the same Reservation is found in the Resumen List of Reservations, then...
                    If excursionG.observaciones = listaExcResumen(i).observaciones _
                    And excursionG.guia = listaExcResumen(i).guia _
                    And excursionG.dtFechaExc = listaExcResumen(i).dtFechaExc _
                    And excursionG.strFechaExc = listaExcResumen(i).strFechaExc _
                    And excursionG.pax = listaExcResumen(i).pax _
                    And excursionG.excursion = listaExcResumen(i).excursion _
                    And excursionG.excursionEspecial = listaExcResumen(i).excursionEspecial Then

                        'Add the rest of the data of the Guide Reservation to the Resumen Reservation in the Resumen List of Reservations
                        listaExcResumen(i) = excursionG
                        'Remove the Guide Reservation from the Guide List of Reservations
                        listaExcGuia.RemoveAt(j)
                        'Restart the cycle
                        GoTo sigExcursion

                    End If
                Next
                'If the Reservation wasn't found in the Resumen List of Reservations...
                'Add the Reservation to the Resumen List
                listaExcResumen.Add(excursionG)
                'Remove the Reservation from the Guide List
                listaExcGuia.RemoveAt(j)
                'Restart the cycle
                GoTo sigExcursion
            End If
            'If the value of estadoPago equals "SIN IMPORTE"...
            'Update j value to compare the next Guide Reservation
            j += 1
        Next
    End If

    'Store all the data from the Resumen List into an array
    Dim arrGuia(listaExcResumen.Count - 1, 18)
    For i = 0 To listaExcResumen.Count - 1
        arrGuia(i, iObs) = listaExcResumen(i).observaciones
        arrGuia(i, iGuia) = listaExcResumen(i).guia
        If listaExcResumen(i).dtFechaExc = Nothing Then
            arrGuia(i, iFechaExc) = listaExcResumen(i).strFechaExc
        Else
            arrGuia(i, iFechaExc) = listaExcResumen(i).dtFechaExc
        End If
        arrGuia(i, iCliente) = listaExcResumen(i).cliente
        arrGuia(i, iPax) = listaExcResumen(i).pax
        arrGuia(i, iCant) = listaExcResumen(i).cant
        arrGuia(i, iExc) = listaExcResumen(i).excursion
        arrGuia(i, iExcEsp) = listaExcResumen(i).excursionEspecial
        arrGuia(i, iExtras) = listaExcResumen(i).extras
        arrGuia(i, iObsProv) = listaExcResumen(i).observacionesProveedores
        arrGuia(i, iTarSin) = listaExcResumen(i).tarSinIva
        arrGuia(i, iTarCon) = listaExcResumen(i).tarConIva
        arrGuia(i, iDebe) = listaExcResumen(i).debe
        arrGuia(i, iHaber) = listaExcResumen(i).haber
        arrGuia(i, iFactura) = listaExcResumen(i).factura
        arrGuia(i, iFechaFactura) = listaExcResumen(i).fechaFactura
        arrGuia(i, iFechaPago) = listaExcResumen(i).fechaPago
        arrGuia(i, iEstadoPago) = listaExcResumen(i).estadoPago
        arrGuia(i, iObsPato) = listaExcResumen(i).observacionesPato
    Next

    'Delete all data in the Guide table
    If Not IsNothing(rgRango) Then
        Globals.shGuia.ListObjects(1).AutoFilter.ShowAllData()
        Globals.shGuia.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Delete()
    End If

    'Paste the array on the Guide table
    Globals.shGuia.Range("b2", "t" & listaExcResumen.Count + 1).Value = arrGuia            

End Sub

End Module
```

**Edit:** Every person in the team is using 64-bit Office, me included.
Also the `sigExcursion:` block works just fine. I use it to remove every duplicated reservations. I checked it on an Excel Workbook using VBA and had no problems with it.

Comment: I haven't used VSTO, but would start by looking at the `sigExcursion:` block. Re-evaluate the use of `GoTo sigExcursion` to see that you're receiving the expected behavior. Also, you haven't stated whether you're using 32-bit Office or 64-bit and whether or not all of the computers are using Office with the same bitness.

Comment: I checked the `sigExcursion:` block and it works as inteded. I use it to remove any duplicated reservation and it does just that. Also, all of us are using 64-bit Office.

Comment: Sorry, but just to start with the obvious.  How big is the data you're processing?  Just making sure this out of memory error isn't because it's simply "out of memory".  Perhaps a profiler might be worth looking at.  Use that to track exactly what point memory is getting out of control